# How can i create a file with & sign at the end of filename in linux?

Tags: linux, command

I am trying to create a file name **File&** name using touch command , but it is not creating file but showing some numbers instead.
`touch File&` but its output is `[1] 148916`.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try `man bash`, looking for "escape character", "metacharacter" and "background". Hint: The same problem occurs if you try to create these files: `File;`, File|`, `File>`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`&` has semantic meaning to the shell.  To pass it to `touch` as a parameter you must quote it:

```
touch 'File&' # (or touch File'&', or touch File\&, or ...
```

`&` is a command separator, similar to `;` or a newline, and bash interprets a string like `touch File& touch File2& touch File3&` similarly to the way it would interprete `touch File; touch File2; touch File3;`.  Namely, it would run 3 commands.  The only difference between `;` and `&` is that commands terminated by `&` are executed asynchronously.  (That is what those numbers you are seeing represent.  `[1] 148916` tells you that background job 1 with pid 148916 was created to execute the `touch` command.)  So `touch File&` executes the command `touch` with the argument `File` in the background, while `touch 'File&`' passes the argument `File&` to the `touch` command that is run in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

& means that the preceding commands to the immediate left of the & will be run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are creating a file named `File` because `&` represents a control operator which tells the shell to execute the command in the background, to create a job ( command or a task that is up and running but hasn't yet finished and it's managed by the shell).

You can type `jobs` command to see that your command was running in the backround.

[image]

If you want to create the file with that specific name use: `touch 'File&'` or just escape the control operator `touch File\&`